# (SOLVED)Is it possible to detect the client's unexpected disconnection from the server socket on python?

Tags: python, sockets

```
def startServer():
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
    server.bind((127.0.0.1, 18608))
    server.listen(10)

    while True:
        cSocket, addr = server.accept()
        print('/'+str(addr[0])+':'+str(addr[1])+'connected to the server!')
        data = cSocket.recv(1024)
        while len(data) != 0:
            for i in range(1000):
                cSocket.sendall(i)
                data = cSocket.recv(1024)
```

If I forcibly close the client before the value 'i' reaches 1000, is it possible to detect the client's unexpected disconnection and automatically close the server socket instead of presenting "ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"?

I tried using try/except code and solved! thank you!

Comment: you need to implement some keepalive I thing may be with another socket using udp/tcp in another thread or wait for a timeout

Comment: Would a try/except statement around the call to `recv` work for you?

Comment: I tried using try/except code and solved! thank you!